# background-color not rendering properly in Outlook 2010

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, outlook-2010

So, I've been trying to get this email to render properly in Outlook 2010. However, it also needs to render on the net and I'm trying to avoid using pure table styling for obvious reasons. I have, however, tried adding the tip many suggested in wrapping the whole thing in a table with a background-color, but that does not work properly as demonstrated below.

The following is the link to my current source:

http://rendera.heroku.com/usercode/205175722e616817b5137ef063a660306e46014c

I know that border-radius doesn't work, and won't work, in Outlook 2010 without images. I'm fine with that. However, here is what the page looks like in gmail:

[image: Gmail version]

And here is what it looks like in Outlook 2010:

[image: Outlook Version]

Comment: I discovered [puts mail](http://putsmail.com/) (built by [Pablo Cantero](http://stackoverflow.com/users/464685/pablo-cantero)) the other day, try running your html through that

Comment: According to that, my code is fine in Outlook 2010, so I'm not sure it's going to properly diagnose the problem. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

In html email you need to use `bgcolor="#"` in your tables.

You are getting this issue because your divs are shrinking to your content. Try setting the `width:100%;` on your header and content divs.

I'd still suggest using tables throughout your email though...

Comment: There is no difference when using the inline table attribute.